# AJAX autocomplete in cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

---

I have a cake application running on my local server. What I am trying to do now is  autocomplete.

### autocomplete

agencies_controller:

```
var $helpers = array('Paginator', 'Html', 'Form', 'Javascript', 'Ajax'); 
var $components = array('Filter', 'RequestHandler', 'Session');

function autoComplete() {
    $this->set('agencies', $this->Agency->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
            'Agency.agency LIKE' => $this->data['Agency']['agency'].'%'
    ),
    'fields' => array('agency'))));
$this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

agencies search.ctp:

```
echo $javascript->link('prototype', false);

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Agency');?>
      echo $ajax->autoComplete('Agency.agency', '/agencies/autoComplete')
      echo $this->Form->end(__('Search', true)); ?>
```

agencies auto_complete.ctp:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($agencies as $agency): ?>
        <li><?php echo $agency['Agency']['agency']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

What is wrong about my code with the autocomplete function? Why doesn't it work?

## Update

Firebug output:

Ajax.Autocompleter is not a constructor

`<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
new Ajax.Autocompleter('AgencyAgency', 'AgencyAgency_autoComplete', '/agencies/test', {});
//]]>
</script>`

Comment: use Firebug. But most likely, the ajax view isn't rendered (i.e. you got the default layout in your ajax request).

Comment: you need a developer addon like firebug or something so you can see if it is making the request to the server, and if the server is responding and what it is responding... Sometimes you need o mess with layouts so it work

Comment: With Firebug I've got something like this: Ajax.Autocompleter is not a constructor `<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
new Ajax.Autocompleter('AgencyAgency', 'AgencyAgency_autoComplete', '/agencies/test', {});
//]]>
</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was about scripts. I forget to place scriptaculous to `js` folder.

Comment: Can you post your answer for the rest of the world?

Comment: The code in my question is correct. I just didn't put the [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) in the `app/webroot/js folder`.

Answer (score 2):

At first look in your view you've used $ajax instead of $this->Ajax (relevant in 1.3.x), for the Ajax helper. Is that fixed your problem?

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined variable: Ajax [APP\views\agencies\test.ctp, line 11]